# Storyboard: Enable advanced UI configurations

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I downloaded a GitHub project and I found some of the elements had configurations options that I haven't seen before.

The left one are the advanced configurations, as you can see you can set the corner radius and see the result immediately in the storyboard

How can I enable those options?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is done by creating `IBInspectable` attributes for properties you want to be able to adjust via the Attribute Inspector in Interface Builder.

Check out this in the apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Step 10 talks about the `IBInspectable` attributes.

Comment: I inspected the code and you are correct, IBDesignable and IBInspectable is widely usead leading to all those configurations options in the storyboard.